# Errors adding external lib in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl

I want to add an external library in eclipse,this how i proceed:

```
Projet/Properties/C++ Build/Gcc Linkers/libraries/,
-l /home/Jackie/CodingPackages/SB5/Src/GLTools/include/ and 
-L /home/Jackie/CodingPackages/SB5/Src/GLTools/src/
```

this is the errors i got :

```
make all 
Building target: Chap1
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/prince/CodingPackages/SB5/Src/GLTools/src/ -o"Chap1"  ./main.o   -lglut -l/home/Jackie/CodingPackages/SB5/Src/GLTools/include/ -lGLU -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: fatal error: /home/Jackie/CodingPackages/SB5/Src/GLTools/include/: mmap offset 0 size 4096 failed: No such device
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `-I/home/Jackie/CodingPackages/SB5/Src/GLTools/include/`?

Answer (score 0):

Include directories are specified with `-I` (capital i)

Comment: yeap the one in add Libraries